# How do I clear a cached website from clients' PCs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser-cache

My problem is the following:
I've built a website for an event last year (edition 2014).
Now I've created a website for the same event, but for this year (2015).
However, whenever I visit the website, it opens the 2014 version, even though I've put the other version up...
Pressing F5 refreshes the page en shows the 2015 site.

So I believe the problem is this web page is a cached version and that that's the reason this happens.
Here's my question:
Is there any way this can be fixed?
(Thinking of a JavaScript script to clear every visitor's cache of this website...)

P.S.: The site uses HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript in 2015. HTML4 and CSS2-3 (idk anymore) in 2014 version.

Comment: You could append something like `?v=2015` on the end of your `.css` and `.js` file calls so that the browser re-loads them and doesn't cache the old versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too broad for SO, there are too many ways to do this. @Albzi What about the main page?

Comment: Never mind. I understood after a while. I think my brain broke for a second. @JuanMendes

Answer (score 2):

Do this for css and javascript

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourlink/filename.css?v=2"/>   

<script src="yourlink/filename.js?v=2"></script>
```

Comment: This won't work if the homepage itself is cached.

Comment: that was so helpful , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good cache control tutorial: http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

However if you didn't apply these tricks in your 2014 edition I guess there's no good ways to expire the already cached 2014 edition from users' browsers. Probably the best you can do now is to put 2015 edition at a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear the 'traditional' browser cache via client- or server-side code, at least not in a cross-browser compatible way.  You could tell the browser not to cache your page by sending the appropriate headers or using these meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Alternative you could version all your resources, e.g. img-2015.png versus img-2014.png

Answer (score 0):

If the browser doesn't calculate an expiration date in the past maybe it will try an http request with the HEAD method.  This method should return the same metadata as a GET would do.  So you may be able to trigger a refresh GET request by setting correct http cache headers on the HEAD request.  This should force the browser to recognize its cached version as stale and retrieve the data with a GET.

Answer (score -3):

One option is, you could give the file a different location on the server and do an server-side redirect.